# How to redirect to success page after uploading file using php?

Tags: php, html, redirect

I am trying to redirect to another page after a successful upload.

So I searched for similar answers on stackoverflow but non seems to solve my problem.

This is my form:

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data"
        action="<?php print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>"  method="post">
    <p><input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="9000000" /> <input
        type="file" name="pdfFile" /><br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="upload"  /></p>
    </form>
```

This is my php which includes the header that redirects

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_FILES['pdfFile'] ) ) {
    if ($_FILES['pdfFile']['type'] == "application/pdf") {
        $source_file = $_FILES['pdfFile']['tmp_name'];
        $dest_file = "upload/".$_FILES['pdfFile']['name'];

        if (file_exists($dest_file)) {
            print "The file name already exists!!";
        }
        else {
            move_uploaded_file( $source_file, $dest_file )
            or die ("Error!!");
            if($_FILES['pdfFile']['error'] == 0) {
                print "Pdf file uploaded successfully!";
                print "<b><u>Details : </u></b><br/>";
                print "File Name : ".$_FILES['pdfFile']['name']."<br.>"."<br/>";
                print "File Size : ".$_FILES['pdfFile']['size']." bytes"."<br/>";
                print "File location : upload/".$_FILES['pdfFile']['name']."<br/>";
                header('Location: success.php');
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        if ( $_FILES['pdfFile']['type'] != "application/pdf") {
            print "Error occured while uploading file : ".$_FILES['pdfFile']['name']."<br/>";
            print "Invalid  file extension, should be pdf !!"."<br/>";
            print "Error Code : ".$_FILES['pdfFile']['error']."<br/>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Remove all `print` before your `header('Location: ....')`. All headers _must_ be sent before _any_ output at all. If you have error reporting and display errors turned on, you should see a "headers already sent" error.  It's also good practice to have an `exit;` after a redirect header, to make sure the script stops executing at that point. It also makes no sense to output anything if you're redirecting the user away from it straight away.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Remember that `header()` must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.**

[**PHP HEADER (From php.net)**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

**WITH PHP:**

```
<?php header("Location: LOADFILE.php"); ?>
```

**If you want to use outputs first use `Html` or `Javascript` code**

**WITH HTML:**

```html
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;URL=http://stackoverflow.com">
```

**WITH JAVASCRIPT:**

```html
 <script>window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");</script>
```